# A getURL() handshake failure

Tags: r

I'm trying to communicate (from "R") with a secured site using the `getURL(...)` command, but I get handshake failure; any suggestions to fix it?

```
url <- "https://..."
html_form <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

And the error I get:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: Run this first: `library(RCurl) ;
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))`

Comment: Dear @Zorayr thanks for your help. Applied your suggestion, yet I'm still getting the same error msg. Here is the full https link:

Comment: Dear @Zorayr thanks for your help. I'm still getting the same error msg. Here is the full https link: "https://hb2.bankleumi.co.il/uniquesig4e0824291ffbe1b42058d6558ed87217/uniquesig0/InternalSite/CustomUpdate/eBank_ULI_Login.asp?resource_id=378D02B0A5C6473A8AE939829AE752C0&login_type=2&site_name=leumi&secure=1&URLHASH=b7166c32-9e7e-4cf5-8a40-a8a8b7c294d3&orig_url=https%3a%2f%2fhb2.bankleumi.co.il/uniquesig1b9908d7df383ab420ba70b96d68a3e57b547ee08195a283e71befc045b24685/uniquesig0%2fTRADE%2fbllUsers%2flogin_secured%2fLogin0.asp".  Can I get getURL() to work on this link?

Comment: Hey, I just edited your post since it was in my review queue, I am not an expert on R, but seems like @Maiasaura has a place to start.

Comment: Dear @Maiasaura thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error msg. Here is the https link: "https://hb2.bankleumi.co.il/uniquesig4e0824291ffbe1b42058d6558ed87217/uniquesig0/InternalSite/CustomUpdate/eBank_ULI_Login.asp?resource_id=378D02B0A5C6473A8AE939829AE752C0&login_type=2&site_name=leumi&secure=1&URLHASH=b7166c32-9e7e-4cf5-8a40-a8a8b7c294d3&orig_url=https%3a%2f%2fhb2.bankleumi.co.il/uniquesig1b9908d7df383ab420ba70b96d68a3e57b547ee08195a283e71befc045b24685/uniquesig0%2fTRADE%2fbllUsers%2flogin_secured%2fLogin0.asp"   How can I getURL() to work on this link?